# Using aggregate with variable names for column names

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have the following data frame:

```
a <- c(1,1,4)
b <- c(1,0,2)
c <- data.frame(a=a,b=b)
str(c)
#  a  b
#1 1  1
#2 1  0
#3 4  2
```

I would like to aggregate the data frame c in the following way:

```
aggregate(b~a,FUN=mean,data=c)
#  a   b
#1 1 0.5
#2 4 2.0
```

However, my main problem is that I will be using a variable for the name of the column

So:

```
d <- 'a'
```

If I try to aggregate using this variable d that contains the name of the column, I will obviously get an error:

```
aggregate(b~d,FUN=mean,data=c)
#Error in model.frame.default(formula = b ~ d, data = c) : variable lengths differ (found for 'd')
```

This works but I then get silly column names. I would like to avoid the extra step of renaming columns:

```
aggregate(c[,'b']~c[,d],FUN=mean,data=c)
#  c[, d] c[, "b"]
#1    1      0.5
#2    4      2.0
```

How to I aggregate and also get the right column names the first try?
(Maybe there is no way to do this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try

```
aggregate(c['b'], c[d], FUN=mean)
#   a   b
# 1 1 0.5
# 2 4 2.0
```

Another option if you are using the `formula` method would be to use `setNames`

```
 setNames(aggregate(b~get(d), FUN=mean, data=c), colnames(c))
 #  a   b
 #1 1 0.5
 #2 4 2.0
```

Comment: I wonder why this produces different column names from what I used.

Comment: @Michal You were using the `formula` method i.e. `aggregate.formula` while I was using `aggregate.data.frame`  You could check the source code of `stats:::aggregate.formula` and `aggregate.data.frame`

Answer (score 3):

If you're not wedded to `aggregate(...)` in base R, here is a data.table solution.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(c)[,list(b=mean(b)),by=d,with=TRUE]
#    a   b
# 1: 1 0.5
# 2: 4 2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cbind` to set the names in `aggregate`.  This method also shows that you can leave out the `data` argument. So if we use your original plan, you can do

```
aggregate(cbind(b = c[, "b"]) ~ cbind(a = c[, "a"]), FUN = mean)
#   a   b
# 1 1 0.5
# 2 4 2.0
```

Comment: This one doesn't work as well since you have cbind(a = c[, "a"]). The first a in that statement is fixed and cannot be substituted by a variable.

Comment: Okay, you could use `get("d")` in place of `"a"`.  But probably safer than that would be `substitute(x, list(x = d))`

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this was to construct the formula parameter in paste:

```
aggregate(formula(paste0("b ~ ", d)), data = c, FUN = mean)
```

This way you can easily pass in as many variables for colnames to as complex a formula as desired.